# How to format hh:mm:ss format which is available as char in dataframe to integer (for student t test)?

Tags: r

I am a novice in R, have got a dataframe imported where one of the columns (MileminDur) is having duration for the student to cover the mile in hh:mm:ss format. another column has categorial data if the student is athlete or not. I want to do student-t test for it. I have 2 questions:-
1. time column in hh:mm:ss is in "char" structure and hence, I guess it can't be used for any calculation needed for student t test. How to do this conversion? Will the conversion be in numeric format?
2. I have missed values in both the columns and as the values are missing without having "NA" mentioned - will our na.omit() funciton be able to give me clean output free from missed values?

Tried some code so that at least I can get omitted values but from the first statement, all the rows get filled with "NA" value and hence the wrong result.

I have got no solution to resolve hh:ss:ss issue yet to even try

```
s_data_ttest1$MileMinDur <- as.character(as.numeric(s_data_ttest1$MileMinDur)) 

ttest1<-na.omit(s_data_ttest1)
```

expectation is removal of missing values + how to work out hh:mm:ss format to some integer kind of format to be able to use in statistical analysis

Comment: Missing value imputation depends on you. Will you replace them with the mean,median,etc or will you remove them from analysis?! That is the question. A question you alone(in my opinion)can answer. You can take a look at `mice` and `Amelia` for that purpose. Also what exactly is the reason for these `NA`s?!

Comment: Thank you @NelsonGon for you response. I got it resolved. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour with `t.test` in R is to use the complete cases, hence ignoring any rows with at least one missing value anyway.

Here is a reproducible example. Consider the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(MileminDur=c("22:11:50","23:11:50", NA, "23:11:51", rep("23:15:00", 11)),
                  athelete=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), 15, replace=TRUE))
print(dat)

MileminDur  Athelete
22:11:50    TRUE            
23:11:50    FALSE           
NA          FALSE           
23:11:51    NA          
23:15:00    TRUE            
23:15:00    NA          
23:15:00    NA          
23:15:00    FALSE           
23:15:00    FALSE           
23:15:00    TRUE
```

Your dataset has 15 rows, and you have 9 "complete cases". Complete cases in a statistical sense means any observation (rows) where all fields / variables have a value that is not `NA`.

Your first task is to convert the `MileminDur` variable to numeric. This can be done with the following code:

```
now <- as.POSIXct(format(Sys.Date()))
dat$MileminDur <- as.numeric(strptime(dat$MileminDur, format = "%H:%M:%S") - now, 
                             units="secs")
head(dat,5)

MileminDur athelete
79910       TRUE            
83510       FALSE           
NA          FALSE           
83511       NA          
83700       TRUE
```

Now you can perform your t.test:

```
t.test(dat$MileminDur ~ dat$athelete)
```

Which returns:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dat$MileminDur by dat$athelete
t = 0.9355, df = 4.0314, p-value = 0.4021
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1391.713  2812.713
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
            83652.5             82942.0
```

Because the default behaviour with `t.test` is to ignore rows with missing values, this is essentially the same as removing the rows with `NA`s manually:

```
# remove any row where there's one or more NA values
dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
t.test(dat$MileminDur ~ dat$athelete)
```

Same output:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dat$MileminDur by dat$athelete
t = 0.9355, df = 4.0314, p-value = 0.4021
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1391.713  2812.713
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
            83652.5             82942.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @onlyphantom for such a quick response and taking detailed example. Much appreciate your selfless support here. I have been able to resolve the issue by this and getting to know the new concepts which you have included.

Comment: You’re welcome @DarpAg and welcome to Stack Overflow! As an asker, you have the privilege to accept the answer that you think if the best solution / most useful (check mark icon next to question). This marks the problem as “resolved” but also help future readers! :)

Comment: Sure @onlyphantom I have marked up the answer . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the readr package. It will convert an hh:mm:ss text input to a variable that represents the overall number of seconds when you load your data.

You can use the related dplyr package to easily filter out the NA times.

If you can save your input data as a csv file, then you can import your data and filter out the NAs using the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read_csv("yourCsvFileName.csv") %>%
  filter(!is.na(timeVariable))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @olorcain for your response - I have got a method to resolve in first response - However, I will try your solution as well to build my understanding. Appreciate your selfless support :)